# Determine vector fields that generate same distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Let $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ be vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$X = x \displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} + \displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}} + x(y + 1) \displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial z}}, \ Y = \displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} + y\displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial z}}.$$

How can I determine $U,V \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $[U,V] = 0$ and the distribution $D(U,V)$ generated by $U,V$ coincides with the distribution $D(X,Y)$ generated by $X,Y$?

I know that $D(X,Y)$ is integrable (as $[X,Y] = -Y$ we have $D(X,Y)$ involutive, hence Frobenius Theorem ensures $D(X,Y)$ integrable), but I do not know if it helps. I've tried to deduce conditions on $U$ and $V$ to have both $[U,V] = 0$ and $D(X,Y) = D(U,V)$ and it led me nowhere.

Any ideas on how to tackle such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, I find it easiest to work with the $1$-form(s) annihilating the distribution. In your case, you can check easily that
$$\omega = y\,dx + x\,dy - dz$$
satisfies $\omega(X)=\omega(Y)=0$. Certainly $\omega=0$ is integrable since $\omega = d(xy-z)$. (This tells you that the integral manifolds are the surfaces $xy-z= c$ for different constants $c$.)

Can you now easily find the $U,V$ you want?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know how to proceed from there. From your answer, it seems as if the problem is solved, so maybe I am missing some results.

Comment: What vectors give the most obvious basis for the tangent space of $z=xy+c$?

Comment: Ah, yes. I believe I got it. Thank you!

Comment: You’re most welcome.