# Can every involutive distribution be generated by vector fields with zero Lie bracket?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

My (hopefully) simple question is this:  Given an involutive ($C^1$) plane field $P$ on a manifold $M$, say an open subset of $R^n$, generated by a linearly independent set of vector fields $(X^1,\ldots,X^k)$, does there always exist a set of vector fields $(Y^1,\ldots,Y^k)$ generating $P$ for which the Lie bracket $[ Y^i,Y^j]$ of any two is zero; i.e. the vector fields commute?

I've seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476075/determine-vector-fields-that-generate-same-distribution) but that is for a specific pair of vectorfields. I've also seen a proof of the Frobenius theorem in which the author, at each point of $M$, finds a local chart in which the spanning vector fields are the first $k$ coordinates, but it is not clear (to me, at least) whether or not the construction is local or global.

I would welcome any responses that help me figure this out.

**Edit**: A related question is, if this is not possible in general, suppose I knew the leaves of the foliation were proper and each was the graph of a function on some domain in $R^n$. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction given by the proof of Frobenius is indeed local. There will be topological restrictions that do not allow what you want globally. For example, if the leaves of the foliation are even-dimensional spheres, then they admit *no* nowhere-zero vector field, let alone a global basis of vector fields.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, let me ask though:  Are there restrictions we could place on the foliation to insure this? I will place the particulars in the question, I think that is the protocol, any ideas you may have would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a hard question and enters into the land of characteristic classes. But the first step is that the Euler characteristic of each leaf must be $0$ — this will allow a single nowhere-zero vector field.

Comment: I appreciate the info. As I put in the question the foliation, in my lay opinion, is somewhat restricted in the way the leaves behave. I was hoping those conditions might make a difference. If the desired behaviot cannot be assured even in that case then I've got my full answer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "proper" leaves (the inclusion map is proper?), but your leaves will be diffeomorphic to your domain, so the topology will come from the domain. That could still be quite nontrivial.

Comment: Got it. BTW, by proper I mean either the inclusion map is proper (as you said) or, given that each leaf L is the graph of a function u (say, L = (x,y,u(x,y)) if M is an open set in three dimensional Euclidean space) that u is a proper map.